# Otros Log Viewer

Tags: otroslogviewer

Okay, so i successfully installed Otros Log Viewer in eclipse using the eclipse marketplace; see screen captures -->[eclipse  marketplace pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRSxL.jpg),
[my eclipse installation details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6LBA.jpg).
However i cant seem to locate it in the eclipse perspective, other or something to launch it.
Question:
Where is the Otros Log Viewer and how can i launch it?
i seen on topic here on Otros log viewer; so that tells me that someone knows how to access it.

cos

Answer (score 0):

On github pages there is a short manual about https://github.com/otros-systems/otroslogviewer/wiki/JumpToCode

There is requirement, that you should add location info to log event (if you are using eclipse)

> Integration with Eclipse requires that log line will contain information about location in code (file and line). Logger can be configured to add this information but it is costly operation (requires throwing and catching exception for every log event).